# What tag is suitable for this question?

Tags: support, tagging

I asked a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171348/how-do-i-describe-even-values-of-the-tenths-digit-of-a-number) on English SE and a user said that it is more suitable here. However, I am unable to post the question on Math SE because I don't know what tag to use.

Comment: Up to my knowledge, there is no standard terms for this sort of numbers. In mathematics, if you have something that you want to describe but lagging a common accepted name for it. You just define them. You can call them even tenths or whatever sensible you can imagine. As long as you define them precisely and the name doesn't collide with other extant usages, you are fine.

Comment: Maybe related to your question: [Can decimal numbers be considered “even” or “odd”?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92451/can-decimal-numbers-be-considered-even-or-odd)

Comment: The "Save us from real mathematics" [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171348/how-do-i-describe-even-values-of-the-tenths-digit-of-a-number#comment357731_171380) kills me.

Answer (score 6):

The tag [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) seems most appropriate to your question; the tag-wiki says

> Questions on the usage and meaning of words in mathematics, the names for mathematical entities, and other such questions.